# Mapping Uploaded Files to different directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using `AjaxFileUpload`

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + e.FileName;
```

This code is uploading files to Files directory under Website folder in `asp.net.`..

How i can map uploaded files to different directory ?

e.g.

Combo Box -> have two option

- Image
- Doc .

If a user select Image then files uploaded should move to Image folder ..similarly for Doc..

How to write code for this in `asp.net c#` ?

Comment: `path = Server.MapPath(theOtherMappedDirectory) + e.FileName` .. select `theOtherMappedDirectory` based on the Combo Box value, file extension, mime, etc. As it is now, this is not a refined question, but rather a request for a walkthough.

Comment: How much thinking did you spend on this problem so far?

Comment: it would be based on combo box selection ! like if a image(option) is selected in combo box then path would reflect to Image folder ..

how can i extract the path from the combo box property.. u getting me ?

Comment: @VikashJha Well, you can get a *value* for the selected combo box item and then you can turn that into the appropriate path .. say the allowed values are "Image" or "Document". Then, create a function: `String SelectedValueToPath(String selectedComboBoxValue)` that generates the desired path.

Comment: sorry for not meeting standard of stackoverflow..

Comment: `Vikash Jha` are you seriously asking how to return the selected value from a combobox? do you have access to internet..? rhetorical question but I know you do so checkout this site here to find the answer to your question [C# examples can be found here](http://www.google.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a conditional to check which option they have selected then place them accordingly. The following code assumes the directories exist, if that's not the case then you'll have to add some logic to create them in the event that they don't.

```
 string path = System.String.Empty;
 if (image == true)
     path = Server.MapPath("~/Files/Images") + e.FileName;
 else
     path = Server.MapPath("~/Files/Docs") + e.FileName;
```

More likely you'll have to do some logic to group them based the file extension. Another option would be to put a radio button for image, in on click listener where the user submits the image you can check whether or not that option is set (my code sample is expecting something like this).